# What is the meaning of the term "beggage"?

Tags: vocabulary

This phrase I heard recently in an airport in the US. I didn't completely understand the announcement, which she first mentioned "begs" which I understand, as in to beg for something. But then she said "Unattended beggage may be damaged or destroyed." I heard it many times, so I remember, this is exactly it. Is it the same meaning, begs and beggage? If so then what is the meaning to destroy the begs?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean "bags" and "baggage" respectively? This is what I infer from context.

Comment: Yes, it's bags and baggage... meaning any unattended luggage, purses, tote bags... etc. will be destroyed (because they assume that there's a bomb in them). We don't do things by half measures in the US. ... *sigh*

Comment: The speaker's accent probably made the word *sound* like "begs", which could easily lead to confusion.

Comment: I apologize but I made this post entirely in jest. R Mac guessed right: next time you're in a major airport in the US, listen to the TSA announcements - she totally says 'beggage' and 'begs'. It might be related to a tendency in Canadian English, not sure. Anyway I found it amusing. (I think it's the same speaker across a lot of airports, now appearing occasionally even in some subway stations). Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is actually [baggage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baggage), meaning suitcases and other luggage. What you heard as "begs" is most likely also "bags".

"Beggage" is not a word.